# cannot display resultant image (php code)

Tags: php

i an trying to get the result(image) from url but there is some thing error in the code 
my code is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$url= $_POST['url'];
$qrurl= 'http://www.qr-code-generator.com/phpqrcode/getCode.php?
cht=qr&chl='.$url.'&chs=180x180&choe=UTF-8&chld=L|0';
$result = file_get_contents("$qrurl");
echo $result;
}
else
{
echo"<form method='post' action='index.php' >
<input name='url' class='material' placeholder='Enter url...' type='url'autofocus/></br><br>
<input name='submit' id='submit' type='submit' value='submit'/></br><br>
</form>
";
}
?>
```

the above code displays nothing
but when i open the url in browser it displays qr code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a (PNG) header since that is the type of file it is creating, and to make sure the URL is in one line and not broken into two; **very important**.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$url= $_POST['url'];
$qrurl= 'http://www.qr-code-generator.com/phpqrcode/getCode.php?cht=qr&chl='.$url.'&chs=180x180&choe=UTF-8&chld=L|0';
$result = file_get_contents("$qrurl");
echo $result;

header ('Content-Type: image/png');
exit;

}
else
{
echo"<form method='post' action='index.php' >
<input name='url' class='material' placeholder='Enter url...' type='url'autofocus/></br><br>
<input name='submit' id='submit' type='submit' value='submit'/></br><br>
</form>
";

}
```

You may also have to add `ob_start();` at the top after the opening `<?php`.

And that the file is not encoded with a byte order mark. This too will throw an error.

The file can be encoded as ANSI or UTF-8 **without** BOM.

Comment: errors:" failed to open stream: Connection timed out" and"Cannot modify header information"

Comment: @SriCharan Go over my answer again; I made a few edits. Follow them completely. This is an encoding issue.